# finding min and maxin list using LINQ and DBNulls

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, max, min

i have the following code which will get the max and min values from a list of type double

```
Dim sprices As List(Of Double) = grp.ProductGroups.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(sm) sm.Field(Of Double)("sprice")).Distinct().ToList()

        Dim min As Integer = sprices.Min()
        Dim max As Integer = sprices.Max()
```

how ever in the first line i get the exception "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type."
how can i avoid this or not add the DBNulls to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) `Double`, which can be expressed as `Double?`:

```
Dim sprices As List(Of Double?) = grp.ProductGroups.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(sm) sm.Field(Of Double?)("sprice")).Distinct().ToList()
```